# If redirected from this site - stay on page , else redirect to mobile page

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have a redirect script on my webpage that says if your browser is less than 699 wide you are redirected to the mobile page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "http://www.idekraft.se/m/";
}

</script>
```

Problem is now - on my mobile page i have a button saying "Take me to the normal webpage".
Due to my stupid screen width redirect script you cant visit the "normal" webpage on your mobile if you so wish.

My question is - how do i solve the script so maybe it says if you are from this adress
www.idekraft.se/m this script doesnt affect you.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using cookies. And I'd prefer jQuery cookie [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

On the mobile page, where you have link, place a listener on `click` event on the link, and before redirecting - set a cookie like `$.cookie('interface', 'web');` and then add check on the set interface on the full web page

```
if (tyepof $.cookie('interface') != 'undefined' || screen.width < 699) {
    // redirect
}
```

So, if someone comes to your full web site it'll be redirected to mobile if the screen is smaller then 699px, and if he click "Full version" link on the mobile site - system sets the cookie and to `interface = 'web'` and your if statement wouldn't be `true` to redirect user.

*Here is the totally working example:*

`deskop.php`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ui = $.cookie('ui');

            $(document).ready(function() {
                if (ui != 'desktop' && screen.width < 699) {

                    $.cookie('ui', 'mobile', { expires: 365 });
                    window.location = '/mobile.php';
                }   
            });

            $(document).on('click', 'a#redirect', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                $.cookie('ui', 'mobile', { expires: 365 });
                window.location = $(this).attr('href');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/mobile.php" id="redirect">Go to the mobile version</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

`mobile.php`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ui = $.cookie('ui');

            $(document).ready(function() {
                if (ui != 'desktop' && screen.width > 699) {

                    $.cookie('ui', 'desktop', { expires: 365 });
                    window.location = '/desktop.php';
                }   
            });

            $(document).on('click', 'a#redirect', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                $.cookie('ui', 'desktop', { expires: 365 });
                window.location = $(this).attr('href');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/desktop.php" id="redirect">Go to the desktop version</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, you need to have `jquery.cookie.js` file in `/js` folder of the document root of your resource.

Hope, that's all you need, cause I have no idea how to describe it more clear...

Comment: Can't get it too work! like this?
  $('#redirect').click(function (){
   $.cookie('interface', 'web');
  });
?

Comment: try:
`$(document).on('click', 'a#redirect', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.cookie('interface', 'web');
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});`

Also check if you connected the jquery cookie plugin on both mobile and destop pages.

Comment: you mean i only link to the jquery plugin on both mobile and desktop?
Isn't this a spelling error in the main function?
if (tyepof) , isnt it supposed to be typeof?

Comment: I've edited my answer, with two written and tested files, which do exactly what you need, and a bit more (redirects to the desktop version if someone come with large screen, and haven't set `ui` cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Add a query string when someone on a small screen device wants to view the main website e.g.

http://www.idekraft.se/m=0

an in your if statement, check the value of `m`.

Pseudo code:

```
if screen width is less than 699 AND m is not equal to zero
   redirect
```

Update: you can also use Session or Cookies. IMHO, the querystring is better.

Comment: While this would work, you'd need to add `?m=0` to every subsequent link in the website.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way out is to use a cookie. When the user clicks the "Take me to the normal webpage", set a cookie:

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.cookie='mobile=no';history.back()">
  Take me to the normal webpage
</button>
```

On your normal page, check for the presence of the cookie:

```
if (screen.width <= 699 && !/mobile=no/.test(document.cookie)) {
    document.location = "http://www.idekraft.se/m/";
}
```